# Disk space consumed

Tags: redhat, postgresql, disk-space-utilization

I have a very serious problem here in one of my client server.
The remote server is installed with REDHAT ES 5.2 and we have a postgresql as database.
I was trying to clone the database.
The hard drive had 32 GB of free space before taking clone.
I started cloning the database and during the process, there was some internet issue and due to this, putty got disconnected before taking clone.
So I opened another fresh session and I was able to see only 2.5GB as available space.
Also I was not able to see the clone in the psql terminal.
Any solution to get the 29GB that was consumed????

Comment: How were you trying to clone the database? With pg_dump?

Comment: How large was the database you were trying to clone? Presumably, there is a temp file that it was using for the clone and you just need to clean that up, but I'm not a postgresql expert. Good luck!

Comment: @ Dan:
I am using psql terminal to clone..
I have figured out the folder under the directory basd on the modified date.
/usr/local/pgsql/data/base/XXXX
If I delete the folder, will it affect the current database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the file in question.  Try the following:

```
find /path -type f -ctime -1 -size +25G -size -32G -print
```

That will find files under /path, created in the last day, over 25 GB and under 32 GB in size.

Comment: If this doesn't work it's possible that several smaller files are causing your problem.  In which case remove the -size... options and look the data over by hand.